# Why my action filter not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc`, i need detect view page refresh with user and do some thing for that purpose read this:
[asp.net mvc - Detecting page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244437/asp-net-mvc-detecting-page-refresh)

for define action filter right click on controller folder and add `RefreshDetectFilter` class :

```
namespace StoreProject.Controllers
{
    public class RefreshDetectFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshFilter"];
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"] = cookie != null &&
                                                            cookie.Value == filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        }
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("RefreshFilter", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

and register that in `Global.asax`,with this way:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RefreshDetectFilter());
```

in my action want to use that action filter with this code:

```
if (RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"] == true)
            {
                // page has been refreshed.
            }
```

but i get this error:
[image]

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: cast the data then compare `if ((bool)RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read values out of `RouteData.Values`, you are given an `Object` rather than a `bool`. You need to cast to the appropriate type before performing your check.

You also don't need to check against equality with `true` as the value is already `true` or `false`:

```
if ((bool) RouteData.Values["IsRefreshed"])
{
}
```